# Python class method also instance method

Tags: python-3.x, class-method, instance-methods

I have a class that in principle carries all the information about it in its class body. When instantiated, it receives additional information that together with the class attributes forms a regular instance. My problem now lies in the fact that I need to implement a method which should be called as class method when it is called from a class object but should be called as regular instance method when called from an instance:

e.g. something like

```py
class MyClass(object):
    attribs = 1, 2, 3

    def myMethod(self, args):
        if isclass(self):
            "do class stuff"
        else:
            "do instance stuff"


MyClass.myMethod(2) #should now be called as a class method, e.g. I would normally do @classmethod

MyClass().myMethod(2) #should now be called as instance method
```

Of course I could declare it as staticmethod and pass either the instance or the class object explicitly, but that seems rather unpythonic and also user unfriendly.

Comment: While this can be done (creating a descriptor similar to ``classmethod``) the purpose of classmethods and regular methods is usually very different. Strongly consider whether the ease of calling one unified method outweighs the ease of knowing what each separate method does.

Answer (score 3):

If the methods are to behave differently, you could simply change which one is exposed by that name at initialization time:

```py
class MyCrazyClass:
    @classmethod
    def magicmeth(cls):
        print("I'm a class")

    def _magicmeth(self):
        print("I'm an instance")

    def __init__(self):
        self.magicmeth = self._magicmeth
```

Comment: Nice, thanks, that should do the trick. Is this still considered acceptable programming style or does it obscure too much what happens in the background?

Comment: To be honest, your whole request seems pretty odd, and I can't say I've ever seen this pattern used before. It's not bad, just strange. Perhaps if your question was a little more explicit about what exactly you're trying to do, it would be easier to make an appropriate suggestion.

Comment: Well the thing is, that by default I only operate on class objects and instance objects only come into play at certain special cases where additional information about the class object is required. Consider this example: Normally a physical unit is something like value*factor (1 Meter) and you can convert it to a diffrent unit simply by making newval = oldval * oldfactor/newfactor.  But sometimes you would maybe also want a power like (1 Meter**2, which in my case would be an instance of the Meter class) but conversion would then require to know the power of the instance.

Comment: @Torilla Note that a squaremeter is *not* the same type as a meter. ``Meter*Meter`` is as a ``Meter`` just as a ``Meter*Second`` -- namely not at all. If you model units like this, your unit system is broken.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by that. I consider any unit (SI unit for that matter) as a seperate "dimension". E.g. I have a well defined baseclass for Length, Time, Mass etc. This is all very fine. The trouble comes in when defnining a Unit from multiple baseunits (e.g. Joule == kg m²s⁻²) where one can operate on the class object defined by its baseunits, but can also add a power (e.g. J² == kg² m⁴s⁻⁴ == (kg m²s⁻²)² etc).

Comment: Just model composites as composites, even if their components are the same. So ``m*m`` works the same as ``m*s``. Then you can also model ``J*J`` with the same means.

Comment: That is actually exactly what I do, I run into trouble when for example making sure that 1Js == kg m²s == 1W, e.g. the class needs to know about its potential aliases that have been definied before and it should not depend on what the user uses as baseunits as long as the type of the unit constructed is the same

Comment: @Torilla It is entirely unclear where the distinction between types (class) and values (instance) comes into play here. A "base unit" like m is fundamentally the same kind as a "derived unit" like J -- you can freely choose which one is the base and which one derived. Either they are all types or they are all values.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a decorator that works like a regular method when called on an instance, or class method when called on a class. This requires a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors):

```
from functools import partial

class anymethod:
    """Transform a method into both a regular and class method"""
    def __init__(self, call):
        self.__wrapped__ = call

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:  # called on class
            return partial(self.__wrapped__, owner)
        else:                 # called on instance
            return partial(self.__wrapped__, instance)


class Foo:
    @anymethod
    def bar(first):
        print(first)

Foo.bar()    # <class '__main__.Foo'>
Foo().bar()  # <__main__.Foo object at 0x106f86610>
```

Note that this behaviour will not be obvious to most programmers. Only use it if you really need it.